# Applying the "easy to difficult" approach in car driving lessons

Tags: learning

I've been wondering, why isn't the "easy to difficult" approach the norm in car driving lessons. For example, first learning all that can be learnt on a car simulator, then driving a simplified, low speed electric vehicle (like a kid electric vehicle) and only last riding a normal training car.

Isn't this done because no one has cared to set it up this way or rather because it would be inefficient as a learning approach?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it would be inefficient.

Given the right conditions, learning to drive can be a risk-minimal activity. If you start in a quiet neighbourhood or stretch of road with no traffic, and let the learner experiment with the pedals, gears etc. on their own time, then they're learning directly the same skills they'll need to know when driving for real. If you learn on a simulator, however, you won't be learning real driving - you won't know how people will react in reality until you get on the road.

Comment: "If you learn on a simulator"- I was referring to the simulator only as one of the steps of the learning process, not the whole process itself.